# printf pointer argument type warning?

Tags: c, clang

Is there a good way to get rid of the following warning? I know it's a type issue in that I'm passing a `unsigned long pointer` and not an `unsigned long`, but does printf somehow support pointers as arguments? The pedantic in me would like to get rid of this warning. If not, how do you deal with printing de-referenced pointer values with `printf`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    unsigned long *test = 1;
    printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long*)test);
    return 0;
}
```

*warning: format specifies type 'unsigned long' but the argument has type*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
unsigned long *test = 1;
```

is not valid C. If you want to have a pointer to an object of value `1`, you can do:

```
unsigned long a = 1;
unsigned long *test = &a;
```

or using a C99 compound literal:

```
unsigned long *test = &(unsigned long){1UL};
```

Now also:

```
printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long*)test);
```

is incorrect. You actually want:

```
printf("%lu\n", *test);
```

to print the value of the `unsigned long` object `*test`.

To print the `test` pointer value (in an implementation-defined way), you need:

```
printf("%p\n", (void *) test);
```

Comment: that will actually produce a warning: an incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing

Comment: @EhevuTov That's from the line `unsigned long *test = 1;`.

Comment: %p produces the address of the pointer. I'm wanting the actual de-referenced value which should be `1`

Comment: @ouah ah, I see. %p gives the value in a ascii hex. I'm getting closer.

Comment: @EhevuTov If you want the value the pointer is pointing at then just dereference the pointer as shown in the answer - printf("%lu\n", *test);

Comment: @ouah thanks for the great answer. Why is my original assignment not valid C?

Comment: @EhevuTov `1` is an `int` value and `test` is a pointer to `unsigned long`. You cannot assign an `int` value to an object of a pointer type in C (with the exception of the `int` value `0`).

Comment: @ouah is 1 not also a short or long? I guess I don't understand why `1` is an `int` when I think it's actually ambiguous. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @EhevuTov `1` is an integer constant of type `int`. It's an `int`, not a `short`, not a `long`. You can assign an `int` to a `long` object (the `int` value is implicitly converted to `long` before the assignment`), so this is valid: `long a = 1;`

Comment: @EhevuTov the standard defines the type of an integral constant in an unambiguous way, look at section 6.4.4.1 in the C11 standard.

Comment: @effeffe you can make it a long by calling it `1ul` (I'm guessing that's in section 6.4.4.1 like EhevuTov said).  The `0` exception is a funny one and (thankfully) C++11 (but not C11) solved that problem by introducing the `nullptr` constant value and the `nullptr_t` type.  But unadorned, a number in C is an int.

Answer (score 1):

You don't *really* need to typecast `test`, the %p will take any pointer (even though the spec says it takes a void*).  Using the `%p` conversion specifier is the safest (and amazingly, most portable) mechanism to print a pointer via printf.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    unsigned long ul = 1;
    unsigned long *test = &ul;
    printf("%p\n", test);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Oh yeah, and also be careful trying to use types like `int`, `long`, etc. relying on their type size.  This is implementation-dependent and can (and does) change on varying platforms and compilers for those platforms.  The C standard just says that `long` has to be at least as large as `int`.  The [POSIX standard for printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap05.html) "length modifiers" don't specify size in bits, but rather by C type.  Thus, you can't presume that `sizeof(long) == sizeof(void*)` (well, they make that assumption in the Linux kernel, but it's married to gcc where that is always true).

Comment: This is more of what I'm getting at, but it returns the address, not the value

Comment: Actually, `%p` requires a `void*`, and passing it a different pointer type invokes undefined behaviour. If you pass it a pointer that in fact has a different representation than a `void*`, things could really break.

Comment: Well, technically the specification says a pointer to void, but if you understand the way that varargs are implemented, it doesn't matter.  However, I suppose that does enter implementation-defined territory (of the compiler).  This is why gcc doesn't emit a warning for it because it can't tell what type of pointer it is, just that it's a pointer.  I'll update my answer to reflect this however.  But as far as seeing odd results, I would be interested to know of an instance (platform, compiler, etc.) where this actually happens.

Comment: `"%p"` does not exactly *"take any pointer"*, it can't print function pointers in a standard compliant way.

Comment: Yes, actually you *can* pass a pointer to a function.  gcc doesn't emit a blip of a warning with -Wall and -Wextra.  The trick here is that we're dealing with vardic arguments and pointers.  In this situation, a pointer is a pointer is a pointer.  On no architecture that I am aware of, are pointers ever a different size within the same process context (although some architectures can use different pointer sizes between user and kernel mode contexts, as expressed via CPU's varying execution privilege modes).  True, this is not *standard*, my point is: show me a context where it doesn't work.

Comment: Ahh, I think I see your point now.  gcc will emit a warning if you pass -pedantic.  Still, I would be very interested if you are aware of cases where this breaks.

Comment: @EhevuTov, crud, I thought you wanted the address! :)  Yeah, just prefix it with an asterisk to de-reference it.

Comment: That wasn't my point: why should we invoke undefined behavior if we have a standard way to do what we have to? Adding a cast to print an object pointer is not a big issue, just a few characters to type; and about function pointers... I think it's not so common to have to *print* them (though there's also a standard way to do that).
Anyway, I don't know about any context where it doesn't work, and I'm as curious as you to know about such a context.
P.S.: don't forget to tag people when you answer them :)

Comment: @effeffe, thanks for your response. What do you mean by "tag", just putting what I did at the beginning of this message? (I guess I'm still new to this site).  While I don't appreciate the down votes, it certainly has sparked my curiosity on the matter, and that I'm appreciative of. The inevitable and cruel casting of values passed via var args is something I learned very early on how to work with, even though it would appear that my methods violate parts of the C and POSIX standards (as the Linux kernel does). C++11 has a new way to deal with this, but I'm not aware of any such change in C11.

Comment: Yes, just like that; if you don't put it in your comment, that person won't be notified about your comment, and he could forget to come back. Sometimes you don't have to do it, like in this comment, since you'll be notified anyway if someone comments your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting