# Getting random result on calculations

Tags: c, printf, scanf

Just started coding and got stuck trying to do math. The code should perform an addition after user input, but I only keep getting random results like `-952492524` when running the code on terminal. How is the correct way to fix this?

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int iquantity, iprice;
    int iresult = iquantity + iprice;

    scanf("%d", &iquantity);
    scanf("%d", &iprice);

    printf("%d", &iresult);
}
```

Comment: ... and `printf("%d", &iresult);` should be `printf("%d", iresult);`

Comment: ..and it should be `int main(void)`.. And `return 0;` in the end won't harm.

Comment: C follows a sequential language paradigm. So the statements you write will be executed on after the other. Now, how can you perform the addition before the vaues of `iquantity` and `iprice` are even input from the user?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [printf pointer argument type warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224917/printf-pointer-argument-type-warning)

Comment: Why would your compiler want to *warn* you about something if it's not important or a common mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to printf was printing the address of the variable and not its value. **scanf** needs the address because it will change the value of the variables; this is passing the variable by pointer.
**printf** only needs to read the value, and so the parameters are passed by value and NOT by pointer.

This is an important concept to learn when coding in C; unlike modern languages, C does not hide variable references: one must embrace the pointer and know when to use it and when not to.

This is an excellent link to learn more on the topic. [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Try it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int iquantity, iprice;

    scanf("%d", &iquantity);

    scanf("%d", &iprice);

    int iresult = iquantity + iprice; /* after scanf, not before */

    printf("%d", iresult); /* and don't need a reference here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you set the value of `iresult` without first giving `iquantity` and `iprice` a value they are by default set to a indeterminate value from memory. You will want to set `iresult` after your `scanf` method calls.

Comment: Not a random value.  Arbitrary perhaps.

Comment: @huck_cussler care to explain the difference?

Comment: @huck_cussler I'm implying it's a indeterminate value, that the value can be whatever was in memory previously. I don't mean a literal random value; I've edited to clarify.

Comment: Random would be if the computer actually chose a memory address at random, as in it somehow shuffled the possible addresses up and picked one non-deterministically.

Arbitrary may appear random but actually may have deterministic underpinnings.  The computer is not picking an address at random, it is extremely well-defined how the computer will behave in picking the address.

However, it is arbitrary in that it is not pre-defined and it almost certainly will be different from run to run.